# Saving a string with variables into file c#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm trying to save a big string into a file

```
string _ULSWcalc = "1.35 * " + _Gd + "+ 1.5 * " + _Wd + "1.5 * " + _Qd " * 0.8";
File.WriteAllLines("C:\\aab.txt", _ULSWcalc);
```

`_Gd` `_Wd` and `_Qd` are all variables and out of the "".
they are all well defined and the program works without the `File.WriteAllLines` line

but if i place it i get these 2 error

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 5):

That's because `File.WriteAllLines()` takes an `IEnumerable<String>` or a `string[]` as the second argument. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx.

If this is just a single line you're writing, do:

```
File.WriteAllLines("C:\aab.txt", new string[]{_ULSWcalc});
```

Comment: really? but since i defined _ULSWcalc as a string, doesnt it recognize it as such?

Comment: Nope; a `string` is just a single instance, but a `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>` are *lists* of instances. Two different concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Check MSDN frequently as very useful source of information: next to `File.WriteAllLines` there is [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which does exactly what you want:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\aab.txt", _ULSWcalc);
```

Comment: i'm new into c# and checked a few places in msdn, but couldn't figure it out, thank you very much